# How to get immediate children in XPath using descendant-or-self:: prefix?

Tags: xpath

Academical question.

Have predefined prefix `descendant-or-self::` in XPath, need to get immediate children (for example, divs) with it.

Without the predefined prefix, it could be `"child::div"`. Any chance to get immediate children **with** `descendant-or-self::` prefix, using some `[conditions]`, etc.?

Comment: Smth like `descendant-or-self::*[(child::*)]/div`, but need to get only immediate children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries `descendant-or-self::*[1]` seems to work fine. To get all immediate children divs, for example, can use `descendant-or-self::*[1]/div`.

Comment: `descendant-or-self::*[1]` is equivalent to `self::*`, it's just selecting the element that is the context node. `descendant-or-self::*[1]/div` is just a long-winded way of writing `div`.

Comment: Yeah, but I can get immediate children of this specific element I'm applying this selector to, through `cssselect` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit like asking how to do addition using the multiplication operator. Answer: don't, it's the wrong tool for the job.

To find immediate children, you want the child axis, not the descendant (or descendant-or-self) axis.

Comment: Thanks! It's an honor to get your answer :)